# Nested for-loop in razor

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a ASP.Net MVC app with Razor. I try to access a collection in the view. Here is my code:

```
@foreach (var question in ViewBag.Questions) {
    <p>@question.Name</p>

    foreach (var answer in question.Answers) {
        <input type="radio" name="@answer.QuestionId" value='@answer.id' /> @answer.Text<br />
    }
}
```

At `foreach (var answer in question.Answers)` I get:

> "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."

I have a `.ToList()` when it comes to the `Questions` collection but what do I do with the `Answers` collection if I want to access ti at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have eagerly loaded the `Answers` collection in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    ViewBag.Questions = db.Questions.Include("Answers").ToList();
    return View();
}
```

And concerning `ViewBag`, well, you could have used a view model instead. Not to mention that your problem is purely related to the data access technology you are using (I suppose EntityFramework) and has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to project the question into a new object and `ToArray` the answers collection.

You can also eager load the Answers collection by using `.Load` or `.Include`